# how to listen for remove child using jquery and firebase

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

the problem is: when i click on the delete button the data remove from firebase but i need to refresh the page , how i can do it with out refreshing the page

```
var userDataRef = firebase.database().ref("User/3N2f2rJSSAZmFOdZEeJdlsuEZam2").orderByKey();

      userDataRef.on('child_added', function(childSnapshot) {
     var key = childSnapshot.key;
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();         
        var title_val = childData.Title;
        var url_val = childData.Url;


        var myRow = $("<tr><td>" + title_val + "</td><td><a href=" + url_val + " target='_blank'> <button class='box'>GO</button></a></td><td><button class='box'>Delete</button></a></td></tr>");
        myRow.find("button").on("click", function(){
          var ref = firebase.database().ref("User/3N2f2rJSSAZmFOdZEeJdlsuEZam2")
          ref.child(key).remove();
        });
        $("#data").append(myRow);
```

i tried event listener child_removed and child_changed but no luck maybe i don't put it in the right place

```
var userDataRef = firebase.database().ref("User/3N2f2rJSSAZmFOdZEeJdlsuEZam2").orderByKey();

userDataRef.on('child_removed', function(childSnapshot) {
  var key = childSnapshot.key;
  var childData = childSnapshot.val();         
  var title_val = childData.Title;
  var url_val = childData.Url;


  // i dont know how to update the table after child_removed event

});
```

Comment: When a child node is removed from the database, Firebase fires a `child_removed` event that you should handle. If you tried that, add the relevant code showing what you tried to your question by clicking the `edit` link under it.

Comment: i updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make sure that `myRow` includes the `key` of the database node it is based on. Typically by include the key as the `id` of the top-level element you generate:

```
var myRow = $("<tr id='" + key + "'><td>" + title_val + "</td><td><a href=" + url_val + " target='_blank'> <button class='box'>GO</button></a></td><td><button class='box'>Delete</button></a></td></tr>");
```

Btw: in modern JavaScript you can use template strings, which are a bit shorter:

```
var myRow = $(`<tr id='${key}'><td>${title_val}</td><td><a href='${url_val}' target='_blank'> <button class='box'>GO</button></a></td><td><button class='box'>Delete</button></a></td></tr>`);
```

Now with this information, you can look up the correct HTML element in the `child_removed` handler, and then remove that element from the page:

```
userDataRef.on('child_removed', function(childSnapshot) {
  var key = childSnapshot.key;    

  $('#'+key).remove();    
});
```

Comment: Good to hear. I hope it also makes sense how this works by inserting the key into the HTML, so that you can use it later. It's a pattern you'll be using a lot when you're dynamically generating HTML from data from an external source.